# I need an explanation about functions that we created

Tags: python, command

why we use `len(command)` in here and that would be great if someone can explain what we did in here (whole things, its getting complicated..)

```
def get_input():
    command = input(": ").split()
    verb_word = command[0]
    if verb_word in verb_dict:
        verb = verb_dict[verb_word]
    else:
        print("Unknown verb{}" .format(verb_word))
        return

    if len(command) >= 2:
        noun_word = command[1]
        print(verb(noun_word))
    else:
        print(verb("nothing"))

def say(noun):
    return 'You said "{}"' .format(noun)

verb_dict = {
    "say" : say,
}
while True:
    get_input()
```

I cant understand the whole things in here I need an explanation about functions that we created above ..

Answer (score 0):

`len` is a built-in function:

```
>>> len
<built-in function len>
```

and it determines the *len*gth of an iterable:

```
>>> len([0,1,2])
3
>>> len('hello')
5
```

In the case of the code shown, it is determining the length of `command` which is presumably a `str`. Therefore, `len(command)` returns the character count of the `command` string.

Comment: why we wrote command[0] then how can we use that command if you explain that I ll be thankfull to you ^^ sorry I'm new in coding..

Comment: I'm not sure *why* it was written that way but `command[0]` translates to (for a string) the first character of the string. i.e. if `command = 'hello'`, `command[0] == 'h'`